# How invoke the rerender?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

This is my problem:
I used a external library in my component, when click a button the library modify the DOM.
I know that Lightning Components may not modify the DOM in the controller, but how can invoke the rerender in the controller ?
Now I am changing an attribute value  only to invoke the rerender, but take a lot of time. What is the best way to do that ?
Thanks for your anwers

Comment: Changing a property on the component is how you do this. Why would you want to invoke a rerender otherwise?

Comment: Because I want to invoke the rerender directly. I don't need to change the value but I do that, because I don't find other way to invoke the rerender

Comment: Invoking the rerender redraws the component. Why would you want to do that if the components state has not changed?